# Using Grep to get the line that had the match and the following line

Tags: bash, grep

I have a file of records. The first line has the name and the following line has the data associated with that person. I want to grep for a persons name and get the line with the name and the line that follows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

grep -C1 *regex* *filename*

Comment: While -C1 will work, it gives more information than necessary. -C1 will give the line preceding and trailing it, -A1 will show only the line and the one trailing it, along with the actual match

Answer (score 4):

grep -A 1 "person name" fileName